# Como pegar um atributo CSS de uma tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, preciso de uma ajuda. Gostaria de saber como pegar valores de uma tag html usando javascript.

como por exemplo: pegar o valor marginLeft de uma imagem que foi determinado por um arquivo css.

espero ter sido claro, obrigado...

Comment: Você usa alguma biblioteca js como jQuery, AngularJS etc..., fica mais facil para te ajudar.  Ex: em jquery pode utilizar `$("#id-elemento").css("margin-left");`

Comment: infelizmente não, eu gostaria de saber como fazer com o javascript puro...

Comment: O exemplo do Miguel abaixo esta perfeito.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para ir buscar propriedades css ao ficheiro de [stylesheets](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.1) (*.css):

```js
var myImg = document.getElementById("my-img");
var marLeft = getComputedStyle(myImg).getPropertyValue("margin-left");
alert(marLeft);
```

```css
#my-img {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img id="my-img" src="https://laravel.com/assets/img/laravel-logo.png">
```

Nota que [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) serve para ir buscar o estilo do elemento ao ficheiro css externo (ficheiro de [stylesheets](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.1)). [Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/71jsb2ch/) uma tem comparação entre os metodos:

```js
var myImg = document.getElementById("my-img");
var marLeft = getComputedStyle(myImg).getPropertyValue("margin-left");
var marTop = myImg.style.marginTop;
alert('margin left (ficheiro externo): ' +marLeft);
alert('margin top (inline): ' +marTop)
```

```css
#my-img {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img id="my-img" style="margin-top:34px;" src="https://laravel.com/assets/img/laravel-logo.png">
```

Comment: Ótimo exemplo !

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: De nada @Drkill32. Enriqueci a resposta mais um pouco. Com uma comparação entre métodos